# vba PasteSpecial não funciona

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Estou recortando os valores de uma planilha e passando para a outra. O recorte é feito sem problemas, os dados estão indo para a área de transferência, mas não estou conseguindo colar.

**Código**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim raizen As String
Dim contador As Integer

contador = TextBox2.Value

If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Informe um valor")
    Exit Sub
Else
    raizen = TextBox1.Text
End If

With Sheets("Plan1").Range("A:A")
Set c = .Find(raizen, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Cut
End With
Sheets("Plan2").Select
Sheets("Plan2").Range("A1").Select
Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    contador = TextBox2.Value + 1
Loop
If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
Worksheets("Plan2").Rows(contador).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End If
TextBox2.Value = contador
End Sub
```

Comment: Eita, o texto da pergunta perdeu toda a formatação :S

Comment: Obrigado pela edição!

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei a resposta! Como estou **recortando** e não copiando eu devo usar **.Insert**, que é o equivalente ao "inserir células recortadas" em vez de usar o .Paste ou .PasteSpecial.

Obrigado!!!